# Symfony3 + Assetic : ParameterNotFoundException

Tags: symfony, assetic, symfony-3.4

I'm working on a Symfony 3.4 application. Assetic bundle wasn't installed, so I made :

```
$ composer require symfony/assetic-bundle
```

and add it in the appKernel.php :

```
    new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
```

It worked perfect. Then, in my app/config/config.yml, I added :

```
# app/config/config.yml
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~

# ...
```

and now my front-end is no more available, this is the error displayed with app_dev.php :

[image]

> ParameterNotFoundException You have requested a non-existent parameter
>   "templating.engines".

Even if I remove the Assetic configuration out of the config.yml the error is here. I have been searching in all my *.yml files I do not find any property "templating.engines" .... any idea ?

Comment: Make sure you have     templating: engines: ['twig'] in your framework config file.  It is no longer there by default.

Comment: Yes, your tip works perfectly ! Thanks @Cerad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the following in the config.yml

```
framework:
     ...
     templating:
            engines: ['twig']
```